# How to start minikube with a fixed server port

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Every time I start minikube it has a new cluster server port.

For example `minikube start` and then `kubect config use-context minikube` results in this in my `~/.kube/config`

```
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Tue, 10 Oct 2023 19:36:48 EDT
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.24.0
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://host.docker.internal:62596
```

I need the `62596` to be static but having tried numerous `start` options like `--apiserver-port` and `--ports` I have not been able to figure out how to achieve this

Is this possible?